# How can I make my print out like a table?

Tags: c++, tabular

I have the following code to print out:

```
cout<<current->bookId<<"\t\t"<<current->bookName<<"\t\t"<<current->year<<"\t\t";
cout<<"Checked out by student "<<current->storedBy<<endl;
```

It looks like this

```
BookId          BookName                Year            Status
1000            Machine Learning                1997            Checked out by student 21000000
1200            Data Mining             1991            Checked out by student 21000020
1400            C++ How to Program              2005            Checked out by student 21000020
1500            Pattern Recognition             2000            Checked out by student 21000000
```

What should I do to make it like that:

```
BookId          BookName                        Year            Status
1000            Machine Learning                1997            Checked out by student 21000000
1200            Data Mining                     1991            Checked out by student 21000020
1400            C++ How to Program              2005            Checked out by student 21000020
1500            Pattern Recognition             2000            Checked out by student 21000000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Set field width**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/) `std::setw` is what you are looking for.

Usage example:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::endl
#include <iomanip>      // std::setw

int main () {
  std::cout << std::setw(10) << "test" << std::endl; 
  return 0;
}
```

Since the parameter is 10, so the `std::setw` will display `"test"` on the 10th, 11th, 12th, 13th characters of the screen.

In your case, you would use a routine similar to this, and with some trials and errors you will achieve what you want:

```
std::cout << std::setw(10) << "col1" << std::setw(5) << "col2" << std::endl;
```

Comment: ...and use `std::left/std::right` to align the output to the left or right.